# Python3 BigQuery or Google Cloud Python through HTTP Proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, httplib2

How to route **[BigQuery client](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-client.html)** calls through **HTTP Proxy** ?

Before Posting this, I tried following but it is still not routing through http proxy. And the Google Cloud service credentials are set through shell environment variable *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS*

```
import httplib2
import socks
import google.auth

credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
http_client = httplib2.Http(proxy_info = httplib2.ProxyInfo(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, 'someproxy', 80));

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, _http=http_client)
```

Outgoing traffic ( 172.217.x.x belongs to googleapis.com ) not routing through HTTP Proxy ,

```
$ netstat -nputw
Local Address           Foreign Address
x.x.x.x                 172.217.6.234:443       SYN_SENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question myself as I found the reason/solution.

**Reason:**

google-cloud-python library uses **httplib2**, As of this writing httplib2 has **two code bases** for python 2 and python 3. The Python 3 version of httplib2 is not implemented with **socks/proxy** support. Please refer to [httplib2's repo#init_py](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/blob/43ff2654ad4f1c90cfb44b8c9bfa9090c0d502a1/python3/httplib2/__init__.py#L821).

**Work Around:**

There is a [discussion](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1346) to move google-cloud-python from httplib2 to urllib3, but in the mean time one can use [httplib2shim](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/httplib2shim)

```
import google.auth
import httplib2shim
import google_auth_httplib2

// More declarative way exists, but left for simplicity
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "someproxy:80"
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "someproxy:80"
http_client = httplib2shim.Http()
credentials, _ = google.auth.default()

# IMO, Following 2 lines should be done at the google-cloud-python
# This exposes client speicific logic, and it already does that
credentials = google.auth.credentials.with_scopes_if_required
              (credentials, bigquery.Client.SCOPE)
authed_http = google_auth_httplib2.AuthorizedHttp(credentials,http_client)

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, _http=authed_http)
```

Comment: get `TypeError: request() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)` error. seems that the http client is incompatible with google cloud _http.py: `self.http.request(url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data)`

Answer (score 3):

Update [Pratap Koritala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43945207/10171028) with latest APIs (google-auth 1.5.0):

```py
import os
import google.auth
from google.cloud import bigquery

os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "someproxy:80"
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "someproxy:80"

credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
credentials = google.auth.credentials.with_scopes_if_required(
                  credentials, bigquery.Client.SCOPE)
authed_http = google.auth.transport.requests.AuthorizedSession(credentials)

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, _http=authed_http)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to create these credentials was by setting it directly in my os environment.

Supposing that you have your [json credential file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#generating-a-private-key) already, maybe this will work for you:

```
import httplib2
import socks
import os
import google.auth

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path/to/your/credentials_file.json'

credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
http_client = httplib2.Http(proxy_info = httplib2.ProxyInfo(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, 'someproxy', 80))
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(_http=http_client, credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: That's not working, it still reaches googleapis.com directly, not through proxy

Comment: I am updating the description of the question with this further problem, I hope you don't mind. This is to have other people focus on the current problem

Comment: Did it return some error when you tried the new credentials? Also, did you try the other socks ('SOCKS4' = 1 and 'SOCKS5' = 2)? Other than that don't quite know why it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, There is no error, As I said it is just that it is not routing through proxy. The network restricts direct traffic. I didn't try with SOCKS4/5 because I only need HTTP, and didn't have the SOCKS environment.

Comment: What you could also try is using your `http_client` to test some  request such as:
`resp, content = http_client.request('http://google.com', 'GET')` and see if it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the following environment variables works for me. But I'm using Python 2.7, with shadowsocks proxy client installed and listening on 1087 port.

```
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://127.0.0.1:1087"
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "http://127.0.0.1:1087"
```